# Question regarding infinite intersection

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Would this intersection be empty?

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-1/n^2, 2-1/n) $

I generated the intervals with few n's,

N=1, (0,1)

N=2, (0.75, 1.5)

N=3,  (0.88, 1.67)
.
.

and I think it would be empty, but I am not sure?

Comment: The intersection of all these sets must be a subset of $(0,1)$. Is there any element of $(0,1)$ that can belong to all those $(1-1/n^2, 2-1/n)$?

Comment: Notice that $1- \frac 1{n^2} < 1 \le  2-\frac 1n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  For any $x \in R$ if there is any $n$ so that $1-\frac 1{n^2}\ge x$ then $x \not \in (1-\frac 1{n^2},2-\frac 1n)$.  As $\sup \{1-\frac 1{n^2}\}= 1$ that means for every $x < 1$ then $x$ is not an upper bound of $\{1-\frac 1{n^2}\}$ so if $x < 1$ then $x \not \in \cap (1-\frac 1{n^2},2-\frac 1n)$.

Likewise if there is any $n$ so that $2-\frac 1n \le x$ then $x \not \in (1-\frac 1{n^2},2-\frac 1n)$.  As $\inf \{2-\frac 1n\} = 1$ that means for every $x > 1$ then $x$ is not a lower boun of $\{2-\frac 1n\}$ so if $x > 1$  then $x \not \in \cap (1-\frac 1{n^2},2-\frac 1n)$

So the only possible $x$ that could be in the intersection is $x=1$.  For $n = 1$ we have $2-\frac 1n \le 1$ so $1\not \in (1-\frac 1{n^2}, 2-\frac 1n) = (0,1)$.  So $1$ is not in the intersection and so the intersection is empty.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the intersection would be empty.

Elements less than 0 and elements greater than 2 are clearly not in the set. It remains to address the intervals (0,1) and [1,2)

Looking at elements in (0,1): None of these can be in the set because suppose one of them is, now we can set n sufficiently large so that the lower bound does not include it.

Looking at elements in [1,2): None of these can be in the set because the case n=1 creates the interval (0,1).

Therefore, no elements can be in our set.

Comment: Bue $1 \not \in (0,1)\supset \cap (1-\frac 1{n^2}, 2-\frac 1n)$.

Comment: yeah, I made a mistake. fixed it.

Comment: "Then we take what fleablood said: Notice that 1−1n2<1≤2−1n. " but notice the second inequality is not strict. To have $1$ in the intersection we would nee $1 − \frac{1}{n^2}\lt 1 < 2−\frac{1}{n} $ and we *don't* have that.

Comment: thank you for your answer :)